# Sleeping in java

Tags: java, swt

i'm trying to make the filled circle to go slowly to the center of the bigger circle
with Thread.sleep(mili seconds) but it does'nt seem to work - it's like the sleep work only once although its in a loop.

here is the code :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseMoveListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MouseListenerUsing {   
    static int i =0, R1=75,inCircleX=100,inCircleY=100,oldX,oldY, outCircleX=inCircleX , outCircleY=inCircleY, R2=200,dist=1;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(430, 460);
    final Canvas c=new Canvas(shell,SWT.BORDER);
    c.setSize(370,380);
    c.setLocation(21, 21);

    c.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) { 
            e.gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
            e.gc.drawOval(outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2), outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2), R2, R2);
            e.gc.fillOval(inCircleX, inCircleY, R1, R1);    
        }       
    });    
    c.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener(){
        @Override
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e){
            if (i==2)   
            {
                if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((inCircleX+(R1/2))-((outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))),2)+Math.pow((inCircleY+(R1/2))-((outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2))+(R2/2)),2))<=R2/2)
                {   // distance between the two centers                                 
                    inCircleX = e.x+oldX;
                    inCircleY = e.y+oldY;
                    c.redraw();
                }
            }
        }       
    });
    c.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) 
        {        
            if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e.x-inCircleX-R1/2,2)+Math.pow(e.y-inCircleY-R1/2,2))<=R1/2)
            {
                oldX=inCircleX-e.x;
                oldY=inCircleY-e.y;
                i=2;
            }
        }
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
        {        
            i=1;
            int flagY=0,flagX=0;

            if ((inCircleX+(R1/2))>(outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagX=1;
            else if ((inCircleX+(R1/2))<(outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagX=0;
            if ((inCircleY+(R1/2))>(outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagY=1;
            else if ((inCircleY+(R1/2))<(outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagY=0;

            double it = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((inCircleX+(R1/2))-((outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))),2)+Math.pow((inCircleY+(R1/2))-((outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2))+(R2/2)),2))); //distance between centers
            while (it>0)
            {
                    if (flagX==1) 
                    {   if ((inCircleX - dist+(R1/2))<(outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagX=0;
                        if (flagX ==1) inCircleX = inCircleX - dist;
                    }
                    if ( flagX==0)  
                    {   
                        if ((inCircleX + dist+(R1/2))>(outCircleX-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagX=1;
                        if (flagX ==0) inCircleX = inCircleX + dist;
                    }
                    if ( flagY==1) 
                    {
                        if ((inCircleY - dist+(R1/2))<(outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagY=0;
                        if (flagY ==1) inCircleY = inCircleY - dist;
                    }
                    if (flagY==0)   
                    {
                        if ((inCircleY + dist+(R1/2))>(outCircleY-((R2-R1)/2)+(R2/2))) flagY=1;
                        if (flagY ==0) inCircleY = inCircleY + dist;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }           
                    c.redraw(); 
                    it--;
            }               
            inCircleX = outCircleX;
            inCircleY = outCircleY;
            c.redraw();
        }
    });
    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed())
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();    
    display.dispose();
  }
 }
```

someone know the problem?

thank you

Comment: Never ever ever ever ever ever ever sleep on the event dispatch thread!

Answer (score 4):

First, you should not sleep in UI thread (UI dispatch thread). If you do so, you're pausing the UI drawing and work, which is bad.

`Thread.sleep` takes **milliseconds** as parameter, not seconds. I highly doubt that you can recognize whether a pause of 10 milliseconds is taking place or not. I think you want 10 seconds, 10000 milliseconds.

Also I see no reason to actually sleep there.

Comment: i want to make it look like the filled ball slowly goes to the center of the larger circle

Comment: Then the while loop should not be there. Your logic should not be messed with UI drawing. Keep your stuff structured and less coupled.

Comment: can you elaborate about why i shouldnt sleep there?

Comment: I already explained why you shouldn't sleep there at the first phrase + in previous comment: you're coupling logic with UI drawing. Please specify what you didn't understand of these or what you need clarification about.

Comment: i need to understand why i cant sleep there - i didnt understand - 

i'm not creating any othere classes

Comment: Well, you need to create other classes, otherwise your code will be too coupled, which is a bad design. Creating more classes is not something you should avoid. In fact it's how you work in Java (just take a look at how many classes there are on the JDK). You can't sleep there because that the UI thread, that is, the thread that draws your UI. If you sleep there, your whole UI will hang for that duration of time, that is, nothing will be drawn/redrawn.

Comment: then how do you recommend me to create another classes so this will work?
thank you for your help

Comment: That's out of the scope of this site; that's quite subjective. I would recommend move all drawing circle code to a new class. Try to make it one class, one purpose. Then mouse listeners simply call the appropriate method from that class.

Comment: I'll try
Thank you, you realy helped me